# Is it possible to directly access CENM rest endpoints to fetch network map details for Corda Enterprise? How to access Rest endpoints for CENM?

Tags: corda, enterprise

We're using Corda Enterprise version 4.2 and we want use these endpoints mentioned in Corda docs:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/network-map.html

We've tried to access these REST endpoints directly using NetworkMap-NLB through PostMan, but couldn't.

Comment: What's the error/problem? It's definitely possible to access CENM endpoints via REST. I suggest to review CENM rather than Corda OS docs: https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.4/network-map-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Like @wawrzek said in the docs it's totally possible to make requests at the CENM API.

link here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.4/network-map-overview.html

Good luck!